# concat multiindex dataframe with only overlapping index levels

Tags: pandas

I am looking for nice way to concat multiindex dataframes with only certain overlapping index levels.

Here is sample two dataframe.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B','C'], ['SubgroupA', 'SubgroupB'], ['X']], names=['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Category'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': np.arange(6)}, index=index)
df
```

```
#Output df
                          Values
Group Subgroup  Category        
A     SubgroupA X             0
      SubgroupB X             1
B     SubgroupA X             2
      SubgroupB X             3
C     SubgroupA X             4
      SubgroupB X             5
```

```
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B', 'C','D'], ['SubgroupB'], ['A', 'B','C']], names=['Group', 'Subgroup', 'Category'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Values': np.arange(9)}, index=index2)
df2
```

```
#Output df2
                          Values
Group Subgroup  Category        
B     SubgroupB A             0
                B             1
                C             2
C     SubgroupB A             3
                B             4
                C             5
D     SubgroupB A             6
                B             7
                C             8
```

Here, we have overlapping index 'B' and 'C' for level 0, and 'SubgroupB' for level 1.
Let's say, I want to concat two dataframe for level 2 only for those overlapping index level 0 and 1.

Here is one way to accomplish it.

```
inter = df.index.droplevel(2).intersection(df2.index.droplevel(2))
pd.concat([df,df2]).loc[
    (
    inter.levels[0],
    inter.levels[1],
    slice(None)
    )
    ]
```

```
#Output
                          Values
Group Subgroup  Category        
B     SubgroupB X              3
                A              0
                B              1
                C              2
C     SubgroupB X              5
                A              3
                B              4
                C              5
```

But the problem of this method is hard to apply it for multiple dataframe.
If I have five multiindex dataframe, then I need to define looks like this.

```
inter = df.index.droplevel(2).intersection(df2.index.droplevel(2)).intersection(df3.index.droplevel(2))....... and so on
```

I believe there is better solution for what I did.
Would you kindly share your idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for processing many index values from list of DataFrames:

```
from functools import reduce

L = [df, df2]
inter = reduce(lambda l,r: l.index.droplevel(2).intersection(r.index.droplevel(2)), L)
```

Or:

```
from functools import reduce
L = [df.index.droplevel(2), df2.index.droplevel(2)]
inter = reduce(lambda l,r: l.intersection(r), L)
```

Another idea:

```
from functools import reduce

L = [df.index.droplevel(2), df2.index.droplevel(2)]
inter = reduce(np.intersect1d, L)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was expecting if Pandas library has simpler solution to this issue. Probably not?

Comment: @SungminSon - Unfortunately not, it is very rare used, so it should be reason not implemented.